# How do I "open a new terminal" for the NODE and NPM tools to be on my PATH?

Tags: terminal

I am learning the basics of Visual Studio Code.  I am reading the first node.js tutorial.  Having successfully installed node.js already, I am stuck at the next sentence that says:

> You'll need to open a new terminal (command prompt) for the node and npm command line tools to be on your PATH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First open the project on Visual studio code then click on View link this will displayed on top left side on your visual code and select the Terminal it will open the power shell and this is on your same directory that you are using...

or if you are using a system terminal or power shell then click command+t it will open the multiple terminals

Answer (score 0):

Click on the "View" menu and select "Integrated Terminal". That will open a powershell or terminal (based on what operating system you are on), that is located att the same folder as the project you have opened.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated!

Comment: @Ramon np, you can thank me by accepting the answer ;)